# Deleting a file that contains some sensitive data from Git history

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-filter-repo

How can I delete `appsettings.json` file from Git history?

I have applied this command in Git:

```
$git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch appsettings.json' HEAD
```

But It does not work with this version of Git(2.30.0.windows.1)

How can I solve it?

if I want to use `git-filter-repo` instead `git-filter-branch`, how can I install and use it for my case?

[image: $git filter-branch]

Comment: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner).

Follow these steps:

1- Install [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/) on your system (for me is Windows 10).

2- Download [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).
I have downloaded `bfg-1.13.1` and located it in the project folder.

3- In the `Git Bash` type this command:

```
java -jar bfg-1.13.1.jar --delete-files appsettings.json
```

after executing you can see some information like this:
[image: executing bfg command]

4- And finally type in the `Git Bash` this command:

```
$ git pull
$ git push
```